# new records to add first row of datagrid view in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

In my VB.Net application I am filling my data grid view like this:

```
Dim cmdd1 As New SqlCommand("DashBordFetch1", con.connect)  
cmdd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure  
cmdd1.Parameters.Add("@locid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = locid
da1.SelectCommand = cmdd1  dr = cmdd1.ExecuteReader 

While dr.Read
    flag = False   
    carid1 = dr("Car_Id")  

    For j = 0 To dcnt1 - 2  
        If carid1 = dgv.Item(0, j).Value Then
            flag = True  
            Exit For    
        End If      
    Next

    If flag = False Then

        If dr("Car_Id") Is DBNull.Value Then
            carid1 = "null"
        Else
            carid1 = dr("Car_Id")
        End If

        If dr("Plate_Source") Is DBNull.Value Then
           platesource1 = "Null"
        Else
           platesource1 = dr("Plate_Source")
        End If

        Dim row1 As String() = {carid1, platesource1}
        DGVDeliverd.Rows.Add(row1)
    End If      
End While
```

..also i am using Timer..every 2 minutes timer will work .some time new records will added to my datagridview..while adding new record that is adding to last row of my datagrid view,,i want to add every time new records to my first row of datagridview. how i can do this?
                 I am using windows forms

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Insert` instead of `Add` to specify the position for the new row. So always insert at position zero:

```
DGVDeliverd.Rows.Insert(0, row1)
```

See [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s80x2556.aspx) for details (screenshot below).

[image: MSDN]

Comment: i have one more condition in my datagridvew: If value1 = 1 Then
                        'DGVall.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = color.Orange
                        DGVDeliverd.Rows(j1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                    End If
                    j1 += 1 after giving your code now this is not happening properly

Comment: @user2648161 I don't see that code in your question, I just answered what you asked. Perhaps you need to ask a different question?

Comment: insted of this code ( DGVDeliverd.Rows.Add(row1)) i try to add this code(DGVDeliverd.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, row1)) but showing error

Answer (score 0):

Use:

> Order by your primary id desc

to keep the latest data on top of the grid

**update #1**

```
DGVDeliverd.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, row1);
```

Comment: sir.please check my code proper.the timer work every 2 minutes,,that time some new records will fetch from database and inserting to last row

Comment: while adding DGVDeliverd.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, row1); this code showing error:'AddAt' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection'.

Comment: ooh!you are windows.Froms not asp.net

Comment: in this case,no I'm srry